# Kendo UI - Hide "End: Never" option from Recurrence Editor

Tags: kendo-ui, recurrence, kendo-scheduler

I am having trouble to hide one option in recurrence editor in a standardized way. I have tried to hide it by custom code but it sometimes creates not predictable behaviour.

This is what I am trying to hide:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got a response from Telerik's support, which I pay for.  Splice the dropdown's data and re-set it:

```
edit: function (e) {
    // remove Yearly" from re-occurence dropdown
    var ddl = $('input[title="Recurrence editor"]').data('kendoDropDownList');
    if (ddl) {
      var data = ddl.dataSource.data();
      data = data.slice(0, 4);
      ddl.setDataSource(data);
    }
},
```

[Working Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@NeliKondova/aMecUWAb).

Comment: This does not solve the question which is regarding the removal of the "never" option. The snipped you provided will only remove 'Yearly' from the dropdown list.

Comment: @Amacado right; just use `data.slice(1)` instead then; you are just manipulating the array; they no longer use an array in the 2020 version though

Answer (score 7):

You need to handle the edit event of the scheduler and hide that option via jQuery:

```
function scheduler_edit(e) {
  // find the recurring dropdownlist 
  var dropdown = e.container.find("[data-role=dropdownlist]").data("kendoDropDownList");

  // handle its change event
  dropdown.unbind("change", hide_never);
  dropdown.bind("change", hide_never);
}

function hide_never() {
  // hide the <li> element that contains the "Never" radio option
  $(".k-recur-end-never").closest("li").hide();
}
```

Comment: I had added other dropdowns in my custom editor template so the above code did not find the recurrence editor dropdown.  Instead I needed to use `e.container.find("[data-role=recurrenceeditor]")`

Answer (score 2):

You also could make this:

in the `edit` event of the widget:

```
  var recurrenceEditor = e.container.find("[data-role=recurrenceeditor]").data("kendoRecurrenceEditor");     

            //set start option value, used to define the week 'Repeat on' selected checkboxes
            recurrenceEditor.setOptions({
                start: new Date(e.event.start),
                change: function (e) { onRecurrenceEditor_Change(e,this); }
            });
```

and then:

```
 function onRecurrenceEditor_Change(e, obj) {
        var buttonNever = obj._buttonNever;

        if (buttonNever) {
            $(buttonNever[0]).parent().remove();
        }
    }
```